# Common properties of index-nodes among unix systems

Tags: unix, operating-system, filesystems

Files on unix are assigned to index-nodes which may vary in layout and content among differnt systems. Usually, there must be common elements across the different implementations. Which are those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the following elements should be available:

- Filetype, 9 RWX permission bits
- Number of references to the file
- Owner's identity
- Owner's group
- File size in bytes
- 13 device addresses
- last read date/time
- last write date/time
- last i-node modification date/time